# Can't hide node "data"

Tags: postgresql-9.5

Column **data** is **jsonb**

```
 SELECT 
    json_agg(shop_order)
    FROM (
    SELECT data from shop_order 
        WHERE  data->'contacts'->'customer'->>'phone' LIKE '%1234567%' LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3 
    ) shop_order
```

and here result as array:

```
[
  {
      "data": {
        "id": 211111,
        "cartCount": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-10-28T12:58:33.387Z",
        "modified_at": "2020-10-28T12:58:33.387Z"
      }
   }
  ]
```

Nice. But... I need to hide node **data**.

The result must be

```
[
  {
        "id": 211111,
        "cartCount": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-10-28T12:58:33.387Z",
        "modified_at": "2020-10-28T12:58:33.387Z"
      }
   
      ]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What about `select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(data)) from shop_order ...`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, it's help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to perform a second select on the result. then specificaly select data

```
SELECT (result->>'data') as result,
FROM result
```

[example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fde96/7/0)